# Error establishing connection in the database. Installing Wordpress on Wampp Localhost

Tags: php, database, wordpress, server, wamp

I have created a database name "hello" in phpmyadmin in MySQL.

In wordpress localhost wp-admin

```
Database Name   hello

Username        root

Password        ' '

Database Host   localhost

Table Prefix    wp_
```

I am installing wordpress 5.3.2 on localhost and Wampp server 3.2.0

The error is as follow:

Can’t select database
We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to select the hello database.

Are you sure it exists?
Does the user root have permission to use the hello database?
On some systems the name of your database is prefixed with your username, so it would be like username_hello. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Do you mean WAMPServer?

Comment: Did you create the database in `mariaDB` or `MySQL` WAMPServer 3.2 installs both and both run by default

Comment: I have created in MySQL

Comment: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-your-windows-computer-using-wamp/
use this

Comment: So you selected `MySQL` in `phpMyAdmin` login page? Because `mariaDB` is the default I think

Comment: yes I have selecte MySQL from the drop down menu in Login Page.

Comment: And what port number is MySQL running on?

Comment: 3308 @RiggsFolly

Comment: Did you tell WordPress that its database was running on a non standard port?

Comment: But the best solution would be to 1) deactivate `mariaDB` 2) Change MySQL port back to 3306 and then you remove this hassle

Comment: Not yet. Okay I should try deactivating the mariaDB. thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly . I have removed mariaDb but the issue is still there.

Comment: Did you switch MySQL to use 3306 as well?

Comment: Ok MySQL is using 3308 right now. Test port is 3306.